# Drop-down menu for a tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

How to apply `@media` for tablet of width 991px? I already the CSS file that is working for mobiles but on switching to tablets the entire css is different. How can I make the same CSS apply for the tablet as it is working for mobiles in the dropdown menu?

I have tried this for the CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    background: black;
}
.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block !important;    }}
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uxB5jEjyjGkcybz1v0ZJ?p=preview). Here I want the drown down menu to work for the width up to 991px but it is working for up to width 768px. How can change it?

Comment: what is your expected output in 991px width

Answer (score 1):

change your div's classs

```
collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-7 pull-right
```

with
    collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12

change in class

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
display: block !important;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The width of <ul></ul> is not changing u can see for width 768 and 992. for 768px ul width is not same as for 992px ul width.

Answer (score 0):

use the following media query for the tablet to apply the same CSS

```
/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
        background: black;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```